# Xcode / iOS: Unit Tests, Schemes, and Configurations

Tags: ios, xcode

My iOS project has five schemes: Local Development, Integration, QA, Demo, and Production. Each scheme uses a differing configuration to control things like network poll frequency, API endpoints, analytics, and so on.

Similarly, we have five corresponding targets: Local Development, Integration, QA, Demo, and Production. Each target has several User-Defined Build Settings, which contain API keys, numeric values for timing, etc.

Our application's `Info.plist` file uses application variables such as `${SOME_ENDPOINT_URL}` to draw in the corresponding User-Defined Build Settings.

To retrieve the variables, I do something like the following:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"Some Endpoint URL"]
```

That would correspond to the User-Defined Build Setting, like this:

```
"Some Endpoint URL" = ${SOME_ENDPOINT_URL}
```

I am now looking at how to configure the project appropriately to perform unit and logic tests.

To build out the tests to determine if the environments are configured correctly, I'm not certain what the best practice is.

- Is it correct to build out five additional Test-specific targets for each environment?
- Or is it better to override the "Run action's arguments" setting for the test component for each scheme, and provide something like an argument to specify which scheme we are looking at?
- Are there any existing references for configuring unit and logic tests for iOS projects with multiple environments? This project's complexity seems to exceed the scope of most documentation.

Comment: Apple keeps making non-backwards-compatible changes to the whole Targets/Schemes system - I think the reason you're not finding docs is that Apple intends/expects to make more of these going forwards, and is hoping to dodge the flak they'll receive. Someone at Apple seems to hate Targets especially, so I would personally go with the "use arguments" approach - Targets may be about to get nerfed (again :( ).

Comment: Rather than having so many different targets, why not have only one target, and five configurations? Instead of Debug and Release you would have LocalDev, Integ, QA, Demo, Prod. You could then create five schemes that build the same target, but with a different configuration.

Comment: @JacobLukas do you know of a good tutorial for what you describe. I've always avoid schemes, but sounds like they can be really useful.

Comment: Here's a link to how to create a configuration in Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/BasingBuildConfigurationsonConfigurationFiles.html

Comment: Targets and Schemes are the preferred way these days rather than using different configurations. A lot of things rely on Debug and Release configurations - don't go down that path, you're in for a bad time. @Kevin - why do you need to test each target? I have a similar setup but do unit tests only on the develop/internal target as testing the others would be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The following are what I do.

Info.plist

- Create a master Info.plist file
- Write a run script (Shell Script) for each scheme to generate a environment-specific Info.plist by modifying settings in the master Info.plist (Use PlistBuddy -c)
- Add the run script to Build Phases (above "Compile Sources")

.h file

- Define configuration settings in a .h file (e.g. config.h)

  ```
  #if defined (CONFIG_FILE) 
  #import CONFIG_FILE
  #endif
  ```
- Import config.h in your code
- Use pre-processor macros for each scheme to select the target .h file.

  ```
  -DCONFIG_FILE=local-env-config.h
  ```